# Oracle SQL insert multiple rows into a table that has a range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar

I found the following answer to a related question.

```
with calendar as(
    select :startdate + rownum - 1 as day
    from dual
    connect by rownum < :enddate - startdate
)
select rownum as "S.No", to_date(day,'dd_mm_yyyy') as "Cal_Dt", to_char(day,'day') as "DayName"
from calendar
```

This SQL generates a number of dates and related info for a range of dates. Can some body tell me how to wrap this into an SQL statement so that the out of the select (all the rows) can be inserted into another table.

Answer (score 1):

If the table you want to insert data into already exists, use `INSERT INTO`:

```
with calendar as ( 
    select :startdate + rownum - 1 as day 
    from dual 
    connect by rownum < :enddate - startdate ) 
insert into anothertable (no, dt, dayname)
select rownum as "S.No", to_date(day,'dd_mm_yyyy') as "Cal_Dt", to_char(day,'day') as "DayName" 
from calendar
```

<strike>Or use `SELECT INTO` syntax to create new table:</strike>

```
with calendar as ( 
    select :startdate + rownum - 1 as day 
    from dual 
    connect by rownum < :enddate - startdate ) 
select rownum as "S.No", to_date(day,'dd_mm_yyyy') as "Cal_Dt", to_char(day,'day') as "DayName" into newtable
from calendar
```

*EDIT -- Actually the comments are completely correct -- wasn't thinking about Oracle :-)  Here is the proper way to create a table from a SQL statement in Oracle:*

```
with calendar as ( 
    select :startdate + rownum - 1 as day 
    from dual 
    connect by rownum < :enddate - startdate ) 
CREATE TABLE newtable
AS 
(select rownum as "S.No", to_date(day,'dd_mm_yyyy') as "Cal_Dt", to_char(day,'day') as "DayName"
from calendar)
```

Comment: -1 SELECT INTO is PL/SQL syntax, not for inserting into a table.

Comment: Yes, if you want to create a new table using data from a `select`, use `create table as select ...`. In Oracle, `select into` is used to fill a plsql variable with the value from the select and **can't** be used to create a new table.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp -- you are completely correct -- wasn't thinking TSQL vs PLSQL -- edited my answer above to show correct usage with Oracle.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The Pseudocolumn `LEVEL` will also work

```
insert into tgt_tbl(id,dt,dy)
select distinct level,:startdate+level-1,to_char(:startdate+level-1,'Day') from dual
connect by level<=(:enddate-:startdate)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE DATES_TABLE 
(
  Date_Field   DATE
);

INSERT INTO DATES_TABLE
(
  Date_Field
)
SELECT ROWNUM - 1 + TO_DATE('01-Jun-2004','dd-mon-yyyy') Date_Field
FROM all_objects
WHERE ROWNUM < TO_DATE('30-Jun-2004','dd-mon-yyyy') - TO_DATE('01-Jun-2004','dd-mon-yyyy') + 2;
```

Try changing those date values to get the values of dates in your required range